# How do I effectively update mongodb while creating user accounts in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I am using `djang.contrib.auth.User` model to create user accounts in MySQL. But I want to hold "unique" sessions, per se, for the users on my website so I thought the best idea was to have each session dependent on the unique username of the individual.

I am using mongodb for everything else but have no clue on how to "fetch" the username (`request.user.username`) of the currently authenticated individual and add it to a BSON table into mongodb.

Or in another django app where the model is based of MongoDB documents how do I fetch the currently authenticated user and add it to mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

I found a round-about way but it works.

On the html page I request the username into a text box that is disabled.

With Javascript I fetch the value of that textbox and insert it into the text box generated by django in `{{ form.as_p }}` which I set the display to as hidden.

But now whenever the button is clicked the mongodb is updated with the current user's username successfully.